# Only using the first character of an input to char variable

Tags: c++, char

So I need this input to only use the first character of the input

```
cout << "\nEnter option ===> ";
cin >> selection;
selection = toupper(selection);
```

for example if you enter "hOttTtt" it only should look at the H.

If i don't do this it takes each letter as an input.

```
        default:
            cout << "\nPlease enter H,D,S,L,F, or X";
            cout << "\nEnter option ===> ";
            cin >> x;
            x = toupper(x);
```

This is the part of the switch statement that runs if it is not a certain letter if that helps.

Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I can't understand what you are trying to do. A [mcve] will help.

Comment: What is `x`? (`string` or `char*`)?

Comment: If you want a single character, then read a single `char`, not a `string` or a `char[]`

Comment: x is a character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the input may contain spaces, you should be using `std::getline` rather than `std::cin` on its own. It's just good practice, even if your sole intent is to look at the first character of the input.

Anyway:

```
std::string selection;
std::cout << "Say something: ";
std::getline(std::cin, selection);
char fstCh = selection.at(0);
```

After this, `fstCh` will contain the first character of the input in `selection`. If you're using a raw `char []` array instead, it's `selection[0]`.